# Pandas - read data (two-row header, index column)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data file that looks like this (miRNA-seq data from TCGA):

```
A X X X Y Y Y Z Z Z
B a b c a b c a b c
0
1   regular 5x9
2   data matrix
3
4
```

`A` describes the first header row, `B` describes the first column.
I want to use `pandas.read_csv` to return a DataFrame such that I can access rows by something like `df[0]` and columns by something like `df['X']['a']`, eventually delete selected rows and/or columns.
On my search I have found that MultiIndex could help my, however `df = pandas.read_csv("datafile", header=[0, 1]); print(df.index)` does return an `Index`.

Thank you for any suggestions.

EDIT: Some sample data (tab-separated)

```
Hybridization REF   TCGA-2V-A95S-01A-11R-A37G-13    TCGA-2V-A95S-01A-11R-A37G-13    TCGA-2V-A95S-01A-11R-A37G-13    TCGA-2Y-A9GS-01A-12R-A38M-13    TCGA-2Y-A9GS-01A-12R-A38M-13    TCGA-2Y-A9GS-01A-12R-A38M-13    TCGA-2Y-A9GT-01A-11R-A38M-13    TCGA-2Y-A9GT-01A-11R-A38M-13    TCGA-2Y-A9GT-01A-11R-A38M-13
miRNA_ID    read_count  reads_per_million_miRNA_mapped  cross-mapped    read_count  reads_per_million_miRNA_mapped  cross-mapped    read_count  reads_per_million_miRNA_mapped  cross-mapped
hsa-let-7a-1    17377   4045.749542 N   47187   7077.368096 N   31765   8956.551210 N
hsa-let-7a-2    34913   8128.517796 N   94766   14213.530526    Y   64148   18087.355487    N
hsa-let-7a-3    17496   4073.455371 N   47683   7151.760928 N   31782   8961.344580 N
hsa-let-7b  33546   7810.249993 N   46089   6912.683963 N   64948   18312.925799    N
hsa-let-7c  1349    314.077006  N   12185   1827.573913 Y   14075   3968.627681 N
hsa-let-7d  1735    403.946335  N   1763    264.424523  N   1176    331.588359  N
```

Comment: please post a sample dataset, othewise you're asking the helper to construct a 5 x 9 matrix for you in order to help you

Comment: And can you post a sample/desired output?

Comment: I think part of your confusion is `df.index` vs. `df.columns`. `df.columns` is a MultiIndex with the levels you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
df=pd.read_csv('zhoop.csv', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

Note: in order to index rows you would use df.loc[rownum], not just df[rownum].

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusion. I had the very same command, however I was not addressing `df.columns` nor `df.loc`.

Comment: Glad I could help! Also, if you aren't aware already, there are two main ways of indexing in pandas, by position (using .iloc or .iat) or by label (using .loc or .at). You will want to know the difference, especially if you'll be deleting rows. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html